# Multiple File Upload in Sails JS from form and then push it S3 one by one

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, sails.js

Well I am trying to upload multiple files from form using Sails JS.
I am not sure how to fetch multiple files when form is posted. Once I receive the files I would iterate over it to upload it to S3 of AWS.

Single upload is working for me but not multiple.
Here the github link where the project is uploaded.
https://github.com/psudeep/sailsFileUpload/

```
module.exports = {
    upload: function (request, response) {
        request.file('file').upload(function (err, file ) {
        //console.log(file.length);
          if(_.size(file) >= 0) {
            file = _.first(file);
            //console.log(file);
            // let file_type = _.split(file.type, '/', 2);
            // let file_ext = file_type[1];
            // let new_file_name = file_name + "." +file_ext;
            let new_file_name = "Test.jpg";
            let originalFilePath = file.fd;

            //S3 upload service working for single upload - this function will be in loop for multiple files
            S3UploadService.upload_file(originalFilePath,new_file_name, function (err, result) {
              if(err) {
                response.redirect("/upload?success=false");
              } else {
                return response.status(200).send({success: true,message:"Successfully uploaded", data: result});

              }
            });
          }
        });
    }
}
```

==========================Form is below=============================

```
<form name="upload" method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" class="input03" name="file[]"><br/>
    <input type="file" class="input03" name="file[]"><br/>
    <input type="file" class="input03" name="file[]"><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Any one who can help to understand how to fetch multiple post after form is posted?
You can take pull from the repo and then commit there as well.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the template file please do the following.

```
   <form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="field">
      <label for="image">Image Upload</label>
      <input type="text" name="file_name" id="name">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file1" multiple/>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Save">
   </form>
```

In the controller do the following. I have just used Math.Random() function to give different name for each file.

```
request.file('file').upload(function (err, uploadedFiles) {
      //console.log(file);
      var data = [];
      async.each(uploadedFiles,
        function (uploadedFile, callback) {
          S3UploadService.upload_file(uploadedFile.fd, file_name + "_"+Math.random(), function (err, result) {
            data.push(result);
            callback(err, result);
          });
        }
        , function (err) {
          // if any of the saves produced an error, err would equal that error
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log(data);
            return response.status(200).send({success: false, message: "failed to upload", data: data});
          }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To understand it, try to `sails.log(file)` (I would recommend to rename `request.file('file').upload(function (err, files)`
2. You will find that when there is more than one file, you have array of files.
3. Then iterate through this array, e.g. with `Array.forEach` and do what you need with every file.
4. You have a bug in HTML. You need to give separate index for every file like:

   ```
   <input type="file" class="input03" name="file[0]"><br/>
   <input type="file" class="input03" name="file[1]"><br/>
   <input type="file" class="input03" name="file[2]"><br/><br/>
   ```
5. Now it should work.

Comment: Can you take pull and commit on repo to understand better